# Postgres' pg_total_relation_size returning unexpected table size for a zfs-based tablespace

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, zfs

I have Postgres 15.1 running on Ubuntu 20.04. Basic FS is ext4, but I have mounted zfs onto a sparse file like this (for compression testing purposes):

```
truncate -s 100G zfspart.dat
zpool create -o ashift=12 -O canmount=on -O atime=off -O recordsize=128k -O compression=zstd pg /root/zfspart.dat
chown postgres:postgres /pg
CREATE TABLESPACE zfs LOCATION '/pg';
```

```
zfs -V
zfs-2.1.6-0york1~20.04 zfs-kmod-2.1.6-0york1~20.04
```

After that, I copied a 12 Gb table into the newly created tablespace:

```
create table if not exists a_copy(
                like a
                including defaults
                including constraints
                including indexes
            ) tablespace zfs;

insert into a_copy select * from a;
vacuum full analyze a_copy;
```

and queried zfs:

```
zfs list
NAME   USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT 
pg    1.22G  95.2G     1.21G /pg
```

And it seemed to provide great compression:

```
zfs get compressratio pg
NAME  PROPERTY       VALUE  SOURCE
pg    compressratio  4.89x  -
```

However, Postgres itself thinks that new table occupies not less space than the original table:
pg_total_relation_size gives almost identical 12Gb:

```
select pg_total_relation_size('a')
12_033_286_144
select pg_total_relation_size('a_copy')
12_031_442_944
```

When I cd into the tablespace, ls -lh shows files occupying approx. 6Gb in total:

```
cd /pg/PG_15_202209061/24412
ls -lh

total 1.3G
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 1.0G Feb 24 00:12 46072
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 1.0G Feb 24 00:12 46072.1
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 1.0G Feb 24 00:13 46072.2
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 1.0G Feb 24 00:13 46072.3
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 1.0G Feb 24 00:13 46072.4
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 945M Feb 24 00:13 46072.5
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres    0 Feb 24 00:12 46075
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 8.0K Feb 24 00:12 46076
```

My question is, **how does Postgres arrive at the given relation file sizes, what's the reason for the discrepancy, and who is correct in calculating occupied space, Postgres or zfs?** My particular goal was compression benchmarks, so how do I calculate real size on disk of a relationship (PG table+its indexes) in this setup?

P.S.: I also tried du:

```
du -h
1.3G    .

du -h --apparent-size
6.0G    .
```

Was a mystery where 12GBs in Postgres come from, even if zfs compression is transparent, as it was pointed out to me. But then I realized my indexes on the new table were STILL created in the pg_default. After all, my questions should be reformulated into this one: **is there an easy/elegant way to get a compressed table (and its indexes) size on my system**, given that I can have at the same time many compressed tables? It does not have to be pure sql, I'd be happy with any sql, Python, system utility solution. Right now the only way I see is to use separate pool/tablespace for each table and calling du -h on the relevant dir, but hopefully I'm wrong.

Comment: ZFS is always right about space usage (and OS command not). Please provide all commands mentioned with output. Why did you set those specific parameters on pool creation?

Comment: Thanks for reading, specific pool parameters I used are just one of the possible combinations I am going to benchmark. I provided all relevant outputs I think, which one do you think I have missed? Oh, you mean ls -lh, got it, added.

Comment: I'm confused, why do you think Postgres should report a different size? ZFS compression is transparent.

Comment: Wow. Somehow I thought pg_total_relation_size will return compressed size already, as it "returns the total on-disk space used for that table". So there is no easy way to get what I want from within Postgres?